# Edit /Update with Web API Repository Pattern

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to work out the very basics of updating my database using a Web API Controller that is backed by a repository pattern. So far I have everything working POST, GET, DELETE (Create, Read, Delete). But I'm missing the Update.

Below is my angular code, I'm not going to post the Angular Views/Templates, but just know that they do bind and they work just fine. My problem is only on the Edit View, where I try to update using the `vm.save` function. My save function works fine on the Angular side, but I'm not sure what to do on the Web API & Repository side. You will see that my code to get this working is very basic bare bones. I have all of the code pages from my project in a gist here:

[All Files in Gist](https://gist.github.com/httpJunkie/6baced0c2fa2aabc9e7a)

Just in case you want to see the big picture, otherwise I will just put here the few pages where I am having trouble getting the Edit/Update methods to work in using `http.put` with Angular Controller, Web API Controller & Repository.

**WORKING Angular Edit Controller:**

```
function editFavoriteController($http, $window, $routeParams) {
    var vm = this;

    var url = "/api/favorites/" + $routeParams.searchId;
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function (result) {
            vm.search = result[0];
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert('error/failed');
        })
        .then(function () {
            //Nothing
        });

    vm.update = function (id) {
        var updateUrl = "/api/favorites/" + id;
        $http.put(updateUrl, vm.editFavorite)
            .success(function (result) {
                var editFavorite = result.data;
                //TODO: merge with existing favorites
                //alert("Thanks for your post");
            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("Your broken, go fix yourself!");
            })
            .then(function () {
                $window.location = "#/";
            });
    };
};
```

**NOT WORKING Web API Controller**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id,[FromBody]Search editFavorite)
{
    if (_favRepo.EditFavorite(id, editFavorite) && _favRepo.Save())
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, editFavorite);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

**NOT WORKING Repository**

```
public bool EditFavorite(int id, Search editFavorite)
{
        try
    {
        var search = _ctx.Search.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SearchId == id);

        search(editFavorite).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        var item = "";
    }
}
```

**WORKING Interface**

```
bool EditFavorite(int id, Search newSearch);
```

Again, my only problems are figuring out what to do for the update in the WebAPI `FavoritesController` and `FavoritesRepository`. I have example of how I have done everything else in the Gist, so I'm hoping someone might be able to help me out. I'm just hitting a wall of what I know how to do in Web API.

[image]

Comment: Is the editFavorite parameter coming through as null?  Is the Content-Type header being set correctly in the incoming request?

Comment: i am unfamiliar with what .Name(...) does, but i think it should be _ctx.Entry(editFavorite).State = EntityState.Modified; Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj592676.aspx for examples

Comment: I can double check again, but I think it's coming through fine, My problem is that I have never implemented a update request before and I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up my PUT Action and my Edit Method on the Repository side. I'm sending the id and the editFavorite object the same as I have on other occasions either with delete or add. And I will make sure that that is working properly since you asked, but my main issue is that I'm just stabbing in the dark as for what to do on the C# side of things for this update.

Comment: If you are getting a valid editFavourite object through, then I see nothing wrong with your WebAPI code.  The EF/Repository code I can't help you with.  I also don't understand that search.Name(.. line of code.

Comment: oops that was a typo on my part. Let me fix that.

Comment: Now I removed the `.name` that was a typo. It now looks like what I was trying to use, but if I roll over the `search` on the second line it gives me an error that says:

`Method, delegate or event is expected`

Comment: Did you bother looking at the link I posted above? You don't need any of the "search" gibberish. Also are you calling SaveChanges() on your context? If you don't, changes won't get saved.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link. Let me see if I can get rid of the gibberish. lol Also I will look at the link. I got side tracked by the other answer below.

Comment: Where do you save the updated entity? I don't see any call to SaveChanges.

Comment: Your right, I'm seeing that now. For some reason I thought that the Controller called save but it looks like it only looks to see if it exists? Again guys this is my first FULL CRUD WEB API Rodeo. Let me see if I can add the save and follow what @failedprogramming was telling me.

Comment: You are mixing two different Web API constructs.  IHttpActionResult and HttpResponseMessage.  IHttpActionResult was introduced in V2.2 I think.  Try changing your signature to return that instead of HttpResponseMessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fixed Code:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id,[FromBody]Search editFavorite)
{
    if (_favRepo.EditFavorite(id, editFavorite))
    {
        _favRepo.Save()  
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, editFavorite);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

I am also posting code which should work fine for handling edit on server side using WEB API and Repository Pattern.

**WebAPI Controller:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id,[FromBody]Search editFavorite)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || id != editFavorite.Id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    db.EditFavorite(editFavorite);
    try
    {
        db.Save();  
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!db.SearchExists(id))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, editFavorite);
}
```

**Repository Method:**

```
public void EditFavorite(Search editFavorite)
{
    db.Entry(editFavorite).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public void Save()
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}

public bool SearchExists(int id)
{
    return db.Search.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
}
```

**Modify Interface:**

```
void Save();
void EditFavorite(Search newSearch);
bool SearchExists(int id);
```

**Edit:**

I have made some changes so that only operations that are carried out on your db context is done in repository layer (Data Layer) and the error checking is done in the `WEB API Controller`.

**Suggestion:**

You should inherit `IDisposable` on the interface and implement it your repository class so that your entities are properly disposed...

```
public interface IFavoritesRepository : IDisposable
{
    // code here
}


public class FavoritesRepository : IFavoritesRepository
{
    // code here
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Syed, This looks very similar to a piece of code I was looking at in a Web API tutorial. I tried using the overall idea, and switching out all of my classes and object's etc.. But had no luck. Is there any way you could modify the code to fit the scenario that I have. Until then I will see what I can do with this.

Comment: I appreciate that, I really do thank you for your time and help I am trying to put the pieces together, I will let you know in a few how it goes.

Comment: Sorry for a very late reply here :) I was editing the question... I am currently using this code in one of projects I am working on so I had to copy paste and then edit it a/c to your question. Yes the code is similar to a tutorial because I had learned it from one of the articles on Microsoft's site and just modified it according to my needs... Happy to help if the code works for you :)

Comment: Syed, I just updated my code with your solution. Can you check out the image I added at the end of my question. It has some errors that I got once I implemented your solution.

Comment: Very end of the post, Maybe you were a few seconds ahead of me.

Comment: THere is one small problem that exists with `SearchExists` so I commented that out for the time being just to make sure the rest works, then I can go back and fix that. Since I'm using a repo I can't just check to see if ti exists without using the repo's `GetFavoriteBySearchId` method

Comment: getting close. Im fighting with bool vs void, but I think I can figure out how to remedy that.

Comment: what is the error you are getting now? I have updated the repository, interface and controller code in my last edit... Is it still not working?

Comment: OK now it kicked back over to my angular code. My `editFavorite` is not getting passed and I think I know why. If you look at it, you see that I never define `editFavorite` before  try and pass it over.

Comment: congrats :P I think I deserve an upvote and answer selection lol

Comment: on my http.put call inmy angular controller i changed `vm.editFavorite` to `vm.search` So I got some naming conventions I need to refactor, but it's working!

I think I would like to play with a few things in the code I got from you because right now I have two different save methods in my repository and a few other weird quirks, but at least I have some working code to play with. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: If you want I could send you a file and t4 template that would automatically generate a repository pattern based on your Database...

Comment: I am going to modify your code slightly to match what ended up working if thats ok. It's just a few little things. But might as well make the question and answer correct in case anyone else comes in to take a look. SO they can benefit too. But for the most part you had the right idea the whole time. I just needed some help crafting it to work with my code. Again MUCH THANKS!

Comment: I would definitely like the T4 template. eric@httpjunkie.com or @httpJunkie thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72725/discussion-between-eric-b-and-syed-farjad-zia-zaidi).